# Minimalistic input = bad usability

Tags: interface, users, research

I looking for research about minimalistic inputs: underline.

Name: ________________

Mail:_________________

etc.

Not only in forms but also in site ie. transactions screens. I was reading some research that this form of inputs have very **bad usability.**

But i cant find this resarch now. 
Can you help me with some research about this?

Thanks.
M.

Comment: Do you mean for printed forms? In an electronic form that is not "Mimimalistic" actually, that would need to be formated to look like that. Requires effort to do that look ugly. U_U Unless you are talking about sending a Word document with thoose underscores, that need to be deleted...

Answer (score 1):

**Using the "Big Fish" Approach to Design Decision Making**

If there is research showing serious usability issues with this type of input, then it's probably going to be of interest to the designers at Google, who have spent years and presumably millions of dollars defining their [Material Design language](https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/introduction.html), which makes use of minimalistic underline inputs.

https://material.io/guidelines/components/text-fields.html#

Not that Google, or any other "big fish" company, are incapable of producing unfriendly UI, but you'd have to think that if there serious issues with the usability of these inputs, they'd likely have discovered them, or versions of them at this stage.

In situations like this, whether you're wondering about web form design (Facebook), or a shopping cart detail (Amazon), I think it's reasonable to look to these billion dollar companies and make the assumption that, for they most part, they're not going to be using any building their primary interactions using components that have serious usability issues.

Answer (score 1):

On a site, it can relate to accessibility issues (do they behave differently than normal inputs? Are they true `<input>` elements?), but I'm not convinced that minimalist design is inherently unfriendly.

With simple inputs, it's also rare to *need* hint text. If a form is clear and succinct, it would overall be a better experience. If you're looking for an even more minimalist design on webpages, you could go with placeholders instead of left-aligned labels without losing its readability.

[This](http://www.uxbooth.com/articles/the-new-rules-of-form-design/) article is an interesting related read with further links to research on the discussed topics.